# Is there a word to describe languages that are read/written from right to left?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

Are there words that describe the directionality of languages? I only see compound words, such as left- to- right or top-to-bottom.  I would have thought a human practice so ancient as language would have established words to this effect!!